# Cuánto más rápido es esperable que sea correr un programa de operaciones de criptografía (hashings) usando Java 8 en PC que en un smartphone con ART?

Tags: java, android, criptografía

He tenido que escribir un programa que realizaba operaciones criptográficas (SHA-256) y truncados de strings un determinado número de veces (muy grande). Este mismo programa una vez que funcionaba bien he creado usando Android Studio una APK de forma que la pudiese meter en los smartphones y correr desde ahí el programa introduciendo los mismos parámetros que en el ordenador. He ensayado varios smartphones (todos ya usan ART) y el tiempo empleado para hacer los mismos cálculos en los smartphone de alta gama como el Samsung Galaxy S6 o el Xiaomi MI 5s es alrededor de 50 veces mayor que en el ordenador (los otros smartphone menos potentes ya ni hablamos...), lo cual me parece raro ya que son móviles muy potentes y creo que no hay tanta diferencia de componentes internos como para que la diferencia sea tan grande. Estos son los componentes de cada uno:

1. Ordenador: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz, 3201 Mhz, 4 procesadores principales, 4 procesadores lógicos; 8GB RAM; Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro.
2. Samsung Galaxy S6: Exynos 7420 Octa Octa-core (4x2.1 GHz Cortex-A57 & 4x1.5 GHz Cortex-A53); 3GB RAM; Android OS v6.0.1 (Marshmallow).
3. Xiaomi MI 5s: Qualcomm MSM8996 Snapdragon Quad-core (2x2.15 GHz Kryo & 2x1.6 GHz Kryo); 3GB RAM; Android OS v6.0 (Marshmallow).

Mi pregunta basicamente es, ¿A que se debe esa degradación tan grande en el tiempo de cálculo al pasar mi programa Java a Android? Me gustaría poder justificarlo sabiendo lo que ocurre exactamente porque no creo que sea por la diferencia de componentes y a decir verdad no entiendo mucho de informática (ya que soy ingeniero aeronáutico pero por circunstancias de la vida me tengo que enfrentar a este problema jajajaja). Había leído en la página de Oracle que era alrededor de 3 veces mayor pero 50 me parece demasiado y no sé porqué puede ser.

Si alguien ha experimentado lo mismo alguna vez o sabe mucho del tema agradecería que me echaseis un cable. Espero haber dado la suficiente información, si necesitáis saber algo más que no haya dicho aquí y pensáis que es importante me lo podéis preguntar.

Comment: Hola Rafa, bienvenido! Pese a que la pregunta me parece interesante he votado para cerrarla por muy amplia (y un poco fuera del alcance de este sitio) ya que no es un problema directo con la programacion y fallos de código. Veamos qué vota el resto.

Comment: Respecto a tu pregunta, ten en cuenta por ejemplo las tarjetas graficas. Tienes tarjetas de escritorio, enormes para pc. Y luego tienes las gama "M" para portatiles. Las especificaciones son similares pero el rendimiento ni se acerca (temas tambien de potencia suministrada). Tambien ten en cuenta la velocidad de escritura  y paso de datos entre el programa y el disco duro (usas SSD en pc?) Y por ultimo, los gigaherzios. El pc tiene 4 nucles a 3.2, mucho mas que los moviles

Comment: Sobre los cores, has preparado la aplicacion usando `Threads` para aprovechar todos los nucleos que tienes?

Comment: Hola lois, gracias por interesarte! Respondiendo a tus preguntas no utilizo un disco duro SSD en el PC. En cuanto a lo de los Threads no he usado ninguno a la hora de crear la aplicación y pienso que a lo mejor puede ser que dentro de las clases de JAVA si existan estos Threads que hace que participen los 4 núcleos del ordenador al calcular y al usar el Android Studio las clases de la API ya no son las mismas y no utilizan estos Thread haciendo que no se usen los diferentes cores del smartphone. ¿Piensas que puede ser esto?

Comment: No puedo hacer cálculos en paralelo en el for ya que es aplicar la función SHA-256 de forma recursiva un número N de veces siempre al resultado de la iteración anterior. No son cálculos independientes.

Comment: Ya, elegir la manera en la que usar el multhithreading es complicado. pero si tú no estás creando y manejando los `threats`, no se va a ejecutar `multithreading`. Puedes hacerlo tanto en windows como en android. Eso te dará mejor rendimiento en ambos. (aunque recuerda que hay un limite en los hilos a usar ya que *más hilos no significa mejor rendimiento*)

Comment: Son distintos tipos de arquitectura de procesadores,con sistemas operativos distintos y VM de Java distintas. Habría que entender cuantos procesos están en ejecución en un caso y en otro. Aquí hay mediciones del [Exynos 7420 Octa](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Samsung-Exynos-7420-Octa-SoC.140007.0.html), [Qualcomm MSM8996](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Qualcomm-Snapdragon-820-MSM8996-SoC.156150.0.html) y [i5 6500T](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Core-i5-Desktop-6500T-Notebook-Processor.167404.0.html).

Comment: Hola rafa, interesante este tema, yo igual tengo un Samsung s6, aun siendo un smartphone de alta gama no se compara con un PC, como te te mencionan son arquitecturas diferentes, una opción es dedicar la mayoría de los recursos a tu app cuando se ejecute

Comment: Hola a todos, estoy intentando comparar las benchmark de los procesadores de los móviles y del ordenador a ver si hay algo común que pueda tomar como referencia para responder a mi pregunta pero como la gran mayoría son puntuaciones y no parámetros pues no me queda claro que me sirva algo. Hay una que habla de los flops y es cierto que en los procesadores de los móviles habla de Mflops y en el del ordenador de Gflops pero no sé si es algo comparable dado que no da mucho detalle. También pensado en lo que comentas de los recursos, el móvil seguro que ejecuta muchas cosas por detrás.

Comment: He encontrado esta discusión que me parece muy interesante (https://www.quora.com/Are-smartphone-processors-finally-comparable-to-PC-processors-in-terms-of-performance) y creo que voy a intentar justificarlo basándome en los comentarios de la gente, aunque no acabo de entender muy bien porque los watios con los que se trabaja son tan importantes y determinantes aunque es cierto que los ordenadores no tienen que preocuparse ni de la batería ni de no producir tanto calor.

Comment: @lois6b en realidad preguntas sobre rendimiento de la aplicación son on-topic para el sitio. El problema con esta pregunta es que aún con la información brindada sigue teniendo una respuesta muy amplia.

Comment: Necesitamos conocer más datos sobre tu aplicación. Primero partimos en que no se usa la misma JVM en estos OSs, es posible que en tu PC uses HotSpot u Open JDK mientras que en tus dispositivos de celular usas Dalvik, allí ya que las diferencias de rendimiento serán notorias, esto influye en cómo estas JVMs implementan el JIT y cómo se va a disparar. Luego, está el tema de parámetros de ejecución enviados a la JVM, de los cuales desconocemos, es probable que en la PC se destinen más recursos a usar que en los móviles.

Comment: Otros factores son el procesador y el consumo de energía. Tal como se menciona en el artículo que provees, los procesadores de PC son más poderosos que los procesadores de celulares. Es como comparar un auto de fórmula 1 contra un pequeño escarabajo de los 70's: ambos llegarán a la meta pero en diferentes momentos (sin menospreciar a los últimos porque hacen un buen trabajo rindiendo bastante con poco combustible).

Comment: @lois6b usar más hilos no siempre significa tener mejor rendimiento. Imagina que tienes una habitación de 4 paredes y contratas a un pintor para que pinte las 4 paredes. Si contratas a 2 pintores es muy probable que se termine la tarea más rápido pero no olvides que se debe pagar a ambos pintores por el trabajo. Sucede lo mismo con los hilos: a más hilos, más recursos consumidos. Además, los procesadores solo soportan procesamiento en paralelo real dependiendo del número de cores y del número de hiper threads que posean.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza pero si es lo que dije, "(aunque recuerda que más hilos no significa mejor rendimiento)"

Comment: @lois6b no lo había notado. Disculpa.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza no problem hahah a veces me pasa de pensar algo y escribir otra cosa y tuve que releer lo que puse xD